# Why is this code not downloading a file to my browser?

Tags: php, download, plist

I have been trying to generate and output a plist file to the user on demand. When the user clicks a button, I run the code below:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="Settings.plist"');

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
          <plist version="1.0">
          <dict>
              <key>key</key>
              <string>value</string>
          </dict>
          </plist>';
 ?>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

What do I need to do to get the file download to initiate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you're using for the Content Disposition header is wrong. It looks like you forgot to add the `Content-Disposition: attachment` bit.

The RFC 6266 shows the syntax through an example:

```
Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=example.html
```

You're currently doing:

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename="Settings.plist"');
                            ^
```

This should actually be:

```
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="Settings.plist"');
```

Full code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename="Settings.plist"');
```

Refer to [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) (regarding the use of the `Content-Disposition` header field in the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP)) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The `Content-Disposition` header you're outputting isn't quite correct. (See [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) for the full detailed specification.) It should be:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Settings.plist');
```

You may also wish to ensure that the file isn't cached via:

```
header('Cache-Control: private');
header('Pragma: private');
```

Comment: @Casper Glad to hear it - have fun fetching the file from iOS. (Presume that's what you're paving your way towards.) :-)

Comment: @middaparka it is actually for a Mac app, but I am glad to have this problem worked out. Don't really know how to handle three correct answers, so I had to go by first submitted :/ Thanks!

Comment: @Casper Damn - that was the other option. :-) Incidentally, generally accepting the "first to answer" isn't the best approach - the ideal for StackOverflow is that more detailed/fleshed out answers should rise to the top. That said, in this instance there's not really much between them.

Comment: Cool - another downvote on a correct answer. Have to love StackOverflow these days.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try these headers?

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Settings.' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '.plist"');
```

I appended the date to the filename too, to prevent the browser from caching the file if someone downloads it more than once.

Also make sure there is no content (whitespace) returned to the browser before your headers are output.